# How to update row return in the same row not in lastrow google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a search tool like this:

```
https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/a-simple-search-tool-ui
```

BUT put it in a panel, add an edit button to enable txtboxes and an update button to save changes. But how will i update the existing data in the same row from which i have searched? Is it possible? Yes its updating but it returns to the last row. not in the same row.

```
function updatebutton(e){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('exampleID').getActiveSheet();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

  var row= ss.getDataRange().getRowIndex();

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var timestamp = e.timestamp = new Date() +  
  Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();

  var txt0 = e.parameter.txt0;

  var txt1 = e.parameter.txt1;

  var txt2 = e.parameter.txt2;

  var txt3 = e.parameter.txt3;

  var data = ss.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1,4).setValues([[timestamp,txt1,txt2,txt3]]);

  return app;

}
```

Or is it possible to identify the Row from where i want to input the data? Little help will do. Thanks

Comment: The code you posted does not show any search capability.  If you have code that is finding something, there are ways to figure out what row has the information being found.  But your current code doesn't show anything that finds any information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using code that is searching a spreadsheet, and finding a value in a cell.  Then you want to update that rows data.  If a `for` loop was being used, then the count of the `for` loop could be matched to the row.  If you are getting an array of data, then finding the index of the value in the array, then the index number could be matched to the row number.

You can get the current active row number.  But you need to click in the row that you want updated before the program runs.

```
var theActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
//Logger.log('theActiveSheet: ' + theActiveSheet);

if (theActiveSheet === 'your sheet name') {
  //Ask to Overwrite only if this is the correct sheet
  var updateThisRow = Browser.msgBox('UPDATE CURRENT ROW?', 'Overwrite current rows data', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
};

if (updateThisRow === 'yes') {    
  var currentRow = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var data = ss.getRange(currentRow, 1, 1,4).setValues([[timestamp,txt1,txt2,txt3]]);
};
```

Comment: omg thanks for the reply. i tried but it nothing happens -_- take a look at my app and the spreadsheet

Comment: i'm also looking at ths one but i can't get it right http://quabr.com/28397927/how-to-update-a-google-worksheet-with-javascript please take a look thanks

Comment: You'll need to use debugging tools.  You can add `Logger.log('some text: ' + variableName)` statements to your code, then VIEW the LOGS, to see what the code is actually doing, or step through the code with the debugger.  [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: its says [15-04-04 00:09:56:510 PHT] sheet: null is there any other way to update a row by not clicking the row?....  it might be used by the other user and they can only view the spreadsheet. is there a way i can share you my script? so that u can see the actual prob? thats the only thing and then im done.. please see. thanks for the time

Comment: yes im using searching tool but i put it in my app too... search string then if it exist/match. it will show up to the txtboxes. and by clicking edit just to enable tbxes and an update button to save changes if ever. im also having a prob after i paste ur code.. it gets me an "Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred'' with may next button. in my search and return after with "no other match"-_-  they are in the same panel.. waiting for ur rep.. thankyou

Comment: If you want, look at my profile, and send me an email.